# Changing icon images with the switch statement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, switch-statement

Depending on a notification type, I need to change icon image of this notification.
There are three types of notifications.

notifications_type:

- answer_created
- user_subscribed
- answer_selected

Icon image is placed inside i tag in a span tag. I don't want to use any conditions, instead I want to do this with switch statement. How am I supposed to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="media g-mb-20">
<span v-bind="changeIcon" class="u-icon-v3 g-rounded-50x g-mt-2 g-mr-15 g-height-40 g-width-40 g-bg-gray-light-v5">
  <i class="icon-bubble g-font-size-18 g-color-gray-light-v1"></i>
</span>
  <a href="#"
     class="media-body g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v4 g-py-10 g-px-15 g-bg-gray-light-v5--hover u-link-v5 g-rounded-3">
    <p class="mb-0 g-font-size-16 g-color-gray-dark-v3">
      <span class="g-font-stag-medium">{{ item.message }}</span>
    </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

I suppose that I need to bind a function with the help of a v-bind directive to a span with an icon. Then I would add the switch statement to this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to bind anything, it's just a matter of using the right classes. define your icon as such:

```
<i class="g-font-size-18 g-color-gray-light-v1" :class="switchIcon"></i>
```

then you define a new computed property:

```
computed: {
  switchIcon () {
    switch (this.notification_type) {
      case 'some_type':
        return 'icon-bubble'
      default:
        return ''
    }
  }
}
```

this way, when `notification_type` is equal to `some_type`, your icon will render as:

```
<i class="icon-bubble g-font-size-18 g-color-gray-light-v1"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Do I need to use 'break' after the first case, if I have other two types as well?

Comment: if your `case` statement ends in return there's no need to call break, as the return breaks the execution of the switch. if this is the right answer please remember to select it as the solution :D